# Office 365 Win Add-in: Cannot get the custom property of a exception meeting through Office.js API

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

In my Outlook Add-in, i try to call **Office.js** API to save some information for a meeting. According to MSFT docs, i use [Office.loadCustomPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentcompose?view=outlook-js-1.9&preserve-view=true#loadCustomPropertiesAsync_callback__userContext_) to do it.

My case is:

1. Create a series meeting and use Add-in to set a custom property.
2. Invite some attendees and send it.
3. Change one instance into exception and open it.
4. Open Add-in to get the custom property which i saved before.

My expect result is that Add-in can get it. But actually, it returns null. Also, it works well when i open an occurrence or the whole series meeting.

Here is my sample code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function(asyncResult){
  var customProps = asyncResult.value;
  console.log('property = '+JSON.stringify(customProps));

  var myProp = customProps.get("myProp");
  customProps.set("otherProp", "value");

  customProps.saveAsync(function(result){
     console.log('save result'+JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});
```

And my Outlook version is
[image]

This issue just occurs in the latest Win Outlook(After monthly channel 2005). It works well in Office Online and Mac Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround for this issue:
 Exception (from series) meeting is created
 Gets a webhook with series ID of the parent series
 Retrieves custom property of the series ID
 Then set property it on the exception meeting